# Old project structure in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I think the question says it all: Is it possible to use the old project structure in Android Studio? I wored for a long time with eclipse and was so used to it that the new file structure is now a bit confused to me. So I really want to use Android Studio but with the old project structure. Any ideas how I can reach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change where Gradle looks for source files by manually specifying the `sourceSets` in  `build.gradle`. In particular, you can set it to the 'old project structure' - add this to the `android` block of your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a generel build.gradle or do I have to set this for each project? Where is the file located?

Comment: There is a separate build.gradle file for every project - it is generally located in the project root directory.